# Tab between elements in a GUI layout

Tags: gui-construction, inputfield

If I have a bunch of input fields, I can tab between them quite conveniently, but if I want to navigate between the input fields and another element (in my case, a button), I have to click on the button manually.  Is there any option or other code construct that would allow the user to tab out of an input field and takes the focus to the button? Ideally I could just press enter and the button would activate. A simple example:

```
Column[{
  TableForm[{ 
    Row[{
      InputField[Dynamic@var, Number, ImageSize -> 150], 
      InputField[Dynamic@unit, String, ImageSize -> 150]
    }]// Deploy
  }],
  Button["print", Print[#1] & [Quantity[var, unit]]]
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer. It is a suggestion about how you might simplify your code. I suggest that the simpler expression

```
Column[{
  Row[{
    InputField[Dynamic @ var, Number, ImageSize -> 150], 
    InputField[Dynamic @ unit, String, ImageSize -> 150]
  }],
  Button["Print", Print[Quantity[var, unit]]]
}]
```

will work just a well as the one you have posted. More generally, I suggest never combining `TableForm` with `Row`, `Column`, or `Grid`.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Can I ask why you'd avoid TableForm?

Comment: @user15921. I don't say avoid `TableForm`. It's fine when used alone, `TableForm` is very old -- goes all the back to Version 1. `Row`, `Column`, and `Grid` are much newer (Version 6) and much more capable. They can do everything `TableForm` can do and much more. This means that `TableForm` simply isn't necessary when you use the newer formatting functions. Further, there are situations where the old and new formatting functions don't play well together. In your code `TableForm` wasn't doing any harm, it simply wasn't having any effect.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks for explaining!